# Error trying to enable permission to access Location services on iOS device

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I am developing this `MapScreen` to display a `MapView` with `initialRegion` set to get the coordinates of the user of the device at the moment. But unfortunately it doesn't work as expected & the permissions are not granted.

Here is what I have tried to implement so far:

```
 export default function MapScreen() {
  const [longitude, setLong] = React.useState();
  const [latitude, setLat] = React.useState();
  const [location, setLocation] = React.useState();
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = React.useState();

  const _getLocationAsync = async () => {
      let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMessage('Permission to access location was denied');
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      let geoLocal = Location.geocodeAsync(location);
      setLocation({ location });
      setLat(geoLocal.latitude);
      setLong(geoLocal.longitude);
    };

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    _getLocationAsync();
  });

  return (latitude && longitude) ? (
      <MapView style={styles.map} initialRegion={{
        latitude,
        longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 1,
        longitudeDelta: 1
      }} />
    ) : null // Displays a blank screen if no long or lat found
 }
```

So this code I implemented displays a blank screen meaning no longitude or latitude is set & produces the error: `[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: LOCATION permission is required to do this operation.]`

Answer (score 1):

Add permissions access on the app.json for ios and remember to add the description in brief ex. App would like to access your Camera to capture user image.

```
"ios": {
      "icon": "./assets/images/iosicon.png",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "buildNumber": '1.0.0',
      "loadJSInBackgroundExperimental": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.some.app",
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "APp would like to access your current location to determine",
        "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": "App would like to access your current location",
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "App would like to access your Camera"
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the conditional statement does not have any current function. In this case, the function is executed without permission.

Add `else` or `else if` statement.

```js
  const _getLocationAsync = async () => {
      let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMessage('Permission to access location was denied');
      } else if(status == 'granted') {
              let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
              let geoLocal = Location.geocodeAsync(location);
              setLocation({ location });
              setLat(geoLocal.latitude);
              setLong(geoLocal.longitude);
      }
    };
```

Comment: If you accept the permission, you may not enter the acceptance in the statement of condition statement. Try a refresh.

Comment: If you don't ask for permission when you refresh, you will succeed.

Comment: The acceptance statement or proposition doesn't appear on my device